# How to display all images from directory one after another in qt,opencv

Tags: c++, qt

i try to make GUI Application in QT Creator.İ wanna display all images from chosen directory (a sort of slide show),i read QDir,QStringlist,QFileDialog class references but it doen't work.it shows only last image in folder.

```
 for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
 {

   QImage image2(directory+"/"+fileList[i]);
   ui->label_pic2->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image2));
   //Sleep(550);
 }
```

Sleep function only makes to load slowly not to show one by another.

Comment: Qt is event based. Most straightforward way is to use QTimer. Never block the main thread by sleeping.

Comment: @hyde QTimer works look like sleep.There is no differences.Only last image loads delay 5s etc.i wanna see on screen slide show.

Comment: *"There is no differences."* - that is a rather authoritative statement, considering that you are having a technical problem and someone is pointing you in the direction of a solution...and you didn't try it to see if it helped.  A better reaction perhaps would be a question, like *"What is the difference between using QTimer and sleep?"*

Comment: @Otantik, you might try to call `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` before sleep to let your label repaint itself, however the timer based solution proposed by @hyde seems to be better approach.

Comment: @Otantik In the very high level sense, of allowing your code to be called X seconds later, `QTimer` is like sleep. However, the biggest difference is, `QTimer` will work, while sleeping will not (because it stops the Qt event loop and nothing is going to happen during the sleep).

Answer (score 2):

First you need to undertand that GUI is only updated when you code is not executed and the application can process incoming [events](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html). If you create an endless circle your GUI will neved be updated. That's why you can see only the last image - because you don't let GUI to be updated.

You can force the application to process incoming events by `QCoreApplication::processEvents()`. In this case you will probably see quick flashing of images. But you will certainly need to make a pause after showing of each image. And your `Sleep` will probably work there, but during the pause your application will be freezed without being able to process the events.

That's why you have been suggested to use `QTimer`. It calls a slot in a certain amount of time. All the other time the application is processing messages and updates GUI and so on. When the slot is called you can switch `label` to show the next image. And this is exactly what you need.

Summary:
1. Create a `QTimer`, set interval and connect it to a slot, start the timer.
2. In the slot implementation read the next image in the list and assign it to the `label`.

*Tip*: To track what image is shown create a interger member variable. Set it to 0 when starting the animation, increase it in the slot.